# Best algorithm for character recognition

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am trying to create a hardcoded subtitle ripper from a video.

So far i have done some pre-processing.

1. Get subtitle frame
2. Crop subtitle lines
3. Separate subtitle lines
4. Separate characters.

The major part that is character recognition, is still not done. I tried using tesseract but accuracy is around 60%. Also I tried training character images and then comparing them. But when I run on different resolution video, it failed badly.

Following are the results so far. (Original Image, Threshold, Text Enhancement, Separated characters)

[image: Original Image]

[image: Threshold with 254]

[image: Then text enhancement]

[image: Separating each character]

I did go through K Means and comparing images using Structural Similarity. But nothing worked in my case. As you can see above the image text is very clear.

**Edited:**

**Question**: I want to improve accuracy to 95% or above as the text is similar across all video, i am able to get the clear text or characters as shown above. Which are the best approaches I can try in my case?

P.S: Language is croatian

Comment: Looks like you're getting pretty good results! You haven't actually asked a question though - what are you asking?

Comment: @ChristopherShroba: Edited question.

Comment: Have you tried tesseract?

Comment: @Miki: yes, as mentioned in question, tesseract doesn't really fit in my case.

Comment: Oh, I missed that... however, with proper preprocessing and the correct dictionary that should work much better than 60%

Comment: Yes, i tried to train tesseract on around 20 images all containing two lines. but even if i achieve 90%+ accuracy, i will still not be able to differentiate between wrongly recognized text or correctly recognized text...

Comment: tesseract recognize almost all characters if i add spacing in characters. but failed on characters like 't', 'i', 'l', 'j' 'a' -> 'o' etc

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest two things:

1. Play a bit more with image clean-up
2. Get better OCR. Tesseract is free, but not the best one. If your budget allows, you may look into some commertial ones. For example: [OCRSDK.com](http://ocrsdk.com) This one has some free recognitions available, at least enough to play and see if it works for you.

I tried your latest picture (the one after all cleanings), on [demo page](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo/),  it was recognised almost completely right - see below. Much better than 60% of errors. I am sure that with better image prerpocessing you could improve accuracy even more. [image]

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.

Comment: I am developing an open source app. Which is capable of ripping hard sub from video and generate srt file and then translate it into target language..thats why paid sdk is not an option. also i need accuracy otherwise translation messes up.

Comment: Thats why my point is..is there any algorithm like K-Mean or SVM that i can use on binary text images? (clear text like above) if yes, then any guidelines to implement on binary text image?. this way i will be able to implement OCR with ML on all languages

Comment: BTW, +1 for suggesting ABBYY. I tried on multiple binary images...accuracy is pretty good.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but for good stuff you have to pay. If highly accurate OCR would be any easy as you think, it would be available already. ABBYY has invested hundreds of man-years of engineering to get to the accuracy it has now. Tesseract once was also a commertcial product by HP, then they decided to opensource it. I would assume that dozens of very smart engineers alrady invested tons of time perfecting it, and it is still far from being perfect. You think you can do better? Alone? Ok, good luck.